# How to get FileZilla to start processing Queue automatically at startup?

Tags: reboot, filezilla

I have my machine automtically reboot periodically and when it does, I have to restart the processing of the Queue in FileZilla for it to resume any transfers that were occuring last time I was using it.

I would like to have FileZilla automatically process the queue at startup.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to make it happen automatically, but if you were to have FileZilla start with Windows, you could use an AutoHotKey script to achieve this (obviously you'd also have to have the script start with Windows).

I don't know how to post something that's compiled (in case you don't already have AutoHotKey), but here's the source of a script that works on my machine...

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
 SetTimer, s_CheckWindow, 5000
return

s_CheckWindow:
 IfWinExist, FileZilla ahk_class wxWindowClassNR
 {
  WinActivate
  WinWaitActive, FileZilla ahk_class wxWindowClassNR, , 10
  SendInput ^p
  ExitApp
 }
return
```

The script checks once every 5 seconds to see if FileZilla is running and if so, activates the window and sends CTRL+P to it (the shortcut for "process queue").  Once it sends the CTRL+P shortcut, it exits the script.